# How to iterate on puppet? Or how to avoid it?

Tags: puppet

I have a global string variable that's actually an array of names:

"mongo1,mongo2,mongo3"

What I'm doing here is splitting them into an array using the "," as a delimiter and then feeding that array into a define to create all instances I need.

Problem is, every instance has a different port. I made a new stdlib function to get the index of a name in an array, and am feeding that to the port parameter.

This seems bad and I don't like having to alter stdlib.

So I'm wondering how I could do this using something like a nx2 array?

"mongo1,port1;mongo2,port2;mongo3,port3"

or two arrays

"mongo1,mongo2,mongo3" and "port1,port2,port3"

```
class site::mongomodule {
  class { 'mongodb':
    package_ensure => '2.4.12',
    logdir         => '/var/log/mongodb/'
  }

  define mongoconf () {
    $index = array_index($::site::mongomodule::mongoReplSetName_array, $name)

    mongodb::mongod { "mongod_${name}":
      mongod_instance => $name,
      mongod_port     => 27017 + $index,
      mongod_replSet  => 'Shard1',
      mongod_shardsvr => 'true',
    }
  }

  $mongoReplSetName_array = split(hiera('site::mongomodule::instances', undef), ',')

  mongoconf { $mongoReplSetName_array: }
}
```

the module I'm using is this one:

https://github.com/echocat/puppet-mongodb

---

using puppet 3.8.0

Comment: couldn't do proper puppet syntax highlight, someone could tell me how or add it please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hiera can give you a hash when you lookup a key, so you can have something like this in hiera:

```
mongoinstances:
  mongo1:
    port: 1000
  mongo2:
    port: 1234
```

Then you lookup the key in hiera to get the hash, and pass it to the [`create_resources` function](https://docs.puppetlabs.com/references/latest/function.html#createresources) which will create one instance of a resource per entry in the hash.

```
$mongoinstances = hiera('mongoinstances')
create_resources('mongoconf', $mongoinstances)
```

You will need to change `mongoconf` for this to work by adding a `$port` parameter. Each time you want to pass an additional value from hiera, just add it as a parameter to your defined type.

Comment: how do you add the $port parameter? Like so? mongod_port    => $port

Answer (score 1):

If you are using puppet >= 4.0, use puppet hashes with each function.

Define [hash](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/puppet/3.8/reference/lang_datatypes.html#hashes) e.g:

```
$my_hash = { mongo1 => port1,
             mongo2 => port2, }
```

Next use [each](https://docs.puppetlabs.com/references/latest/function.html#each) function on it e.g:

```
$my_hash.each |$key, $val| { some code }.
```

More about iteration in puppet [here](https://docs.puppetlabs.com/puppet/latest/reference/lang_iteration.html).

Comment: using puppet enterprise, so it's still 3.8

Comment: Sorry I'm not familiar with puppet enterprise. If it has `each` function, the solution should be working.

Comment: enterprise is the same as open source, except usually a bit behind. I'll check out if function exists.

Comment: Nope. It would only work with "--parser future" enabled. You're using puppet 4 already?

Comment: Nope, I'm still using puppet 3.7.x. But in 4.0 "future parser" has became a "standard parser"